# Videview.getduration(); always returns -1? Can we get the exact duration of video file?

Tags: android, file, android-videoview, duration

How to get the exact duration of video file? here is my code:

```
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filenamePlay));
long duration = videoview.getDuration();
Log.e("Duration of viddo", String.valueOf(duration));
```

It always return -1 value. My path is 100% fine. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(filenamePlay);
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Video.query(res, data.getData(), new String[]{MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION});
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String duration = cursor.getString(0);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + duration);
}
```

Now use this string anywhere and display the duration. Like if you want to print this in a text-view then

```
textview.setText(duration);
```

Comment: I tried this code before I dont know what to put instead of data.getData() ??

Comment: If you are using intent then you don't need to replace `data.getData()`

Comment: you mean to say data is my filepath ?

Comment: It throws null exception: Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Video.query(getContentResolver(),Uri.parse(filenamePlay),
                new String[] { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION });

Comment: Brother there is only a problem with data.getdata() otherwise its all fine.

Comment: I am using "getContentResolver()" instead of res it throws null